# Regression - many samples have the same target

Tags: regression, boosting, structured-prediction

I have a machine learning problem in which I have a many-to-one relationship from samples to targets. I have ~3k samples but only 11 targets with a shared key `YEAR`

My first approach was to reshape the targets to get a one-to-one relationship, but then i get a lot of samples with the same target value. Attached is a figure that shows many vertical lines. XGBoost seems to struggle with that.

[image]

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd
dummy_data = pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.product(["A","B","C"],["R","S","T"],range(2006,2016))),columns=["CAT1","CAT2","YEAR"])
dummy_data["F1"] = np.random.rand(90)
dummy_data["F2"] = np.random.rand(90)
dummy_data["F3"] = np.random.rand(90)

target = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(11).tolist(),range(2006,2017),columns=["Target"])
target.index.name = "YEAR"

train = pd.merge(dummy_data,target.reset_index(),how="left",on="YEAR")
```

Also, I would like to learn the function how the different `CAT1,CAT2` provide to the target.

Is there a better python library I can use to do that?

I've been looking into structured learning and parsimony, but another problem in my data is that the number of `CAT1,CAT2` combinations is not consistent.

Another approach was to concatenate all `CAT1,CAT2` to one sample per `YEAR` but then I have plenty of NaNs for missing values and my feature size is increadibly high > 15k

What machine learning approach can I use?

Comment: Does it make sense to take the mean (average) or median value for each of the multiples?